# Can't enter @ in VS Code Terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, unix, terminal, oh-my-zsh

I have a problem with my VSC terminal if I try to type @ symbol, I get a pair of single quotes.

I checked for solutions online, but can't find anything that works. I also checked the keyboard shortcuts, but nothing is assigned to that command.

I can type the @ symbol in the regular terminal.

Version: 1.80.1 (Universal)
Commit: 74f6148eb9ea00507ec113ec51c489d6ffb4b771
Date: 2023-07-12T17:20:23.298Z
Electron: 22.3.14
ElectronBuildId: 21893604
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 21.6.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSCf5.png)

[image]

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: What do you see when you [troubleshoot your keybindings](//github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues)? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post.

Comment: What shell options do you have? Of those shells, which ones does this happen for?

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them. If you re-read my comment carefully, you will see that I already wrote: "_Please copy and paste the output of the Help: About command **into your question post**._"